# Encryption with data loss protection

Tags: encryption

Is there an existing format out there that not only encrypts data but also protects against loss of data much like the QR codes can lose up to 33% of it's bits and the message is still recoverable.

I don't want to say encryption with RAID 5 but I guess it's the same concept.

Comment: The obvious way to do this is encrypt your data normally, and then apply an unkeyed redundancy transform (such as what's in QR); that'd meet the requirements, and we don't have to worry about the redundancy aspects from causing security problems.

Comment: I know this will change my question. my ultimate goal is to distribute a book and have a way that readers can validate that the contents are unaltered. The obvious solution would be to distribute a hash along with the book. However I'm thinking long term and possible corruption of both the book and the hash or loss of the hash to where I'm thinking an encryption algo can solve the problem of the hash as it's built in to the text. I'm probably WAY overthinking this.

Comment: If you want to ensure authentication, adding a hash is the wrong answer (anyone could modify your book and update the hash).  Instead, I suggest you start looking at signatures; in short, you'd sign your book with your private key; someone (who gets a verified copy of your public key; the "verified" is the tricky part) can verify that the book is precisely as you signed it.

Comment: What @poncho says is along the right track, but it sounds like you want your distributed book to be "error tolerant". In other words, if some parts of the file get corrupted, the person should still be able to read and verify it. Is that correct?

Comment: yes, error tolerant is a great term for it.

Comment: Now, specifically what "security" pillars do you care about? The typical pillars we see are confidentiality (only who you say can have the book can have it), integrity (that the book hasn't changed), authenticity (that the book came from you, or that you are really the one who sent it to them).

Comment: @mikeazo integrity

Comment: Perhaps it's not what you need, but you may be interested in [locality sensitive hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing) -- it's what Google uses to identify identical web pages, even where there's slight difference in HTML content (different ads, etc.). It's been a while since I've looked at LSH, but I think it allows the recipient to calculate the *distance* of their copy of the book from the original book.

Comment: It sounds a little like you want two different things. A) A way for people to check authenticity of the book, i.e., that they were not given an altered copy. B) A way to correct errors in a somewhat altered book to get back to the original. A) You should be able to do by signing the book using a signature scheme. For B) what you are probably looking for is some error correcting code, which is an encoding that allows you to do exactly B). To get both properties probably you can use a combination of the two. A scheme that does both at once does not spring to my mind though.